# Memory leak issue with printing wchar_t to console?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory, wchar-t

In a c++ program, I have a pointer to a wchar_t value. In order to get the value at the adress the pointer is pointing to I am doing the following:

```
std::wstring myAnimalID;
wchart_t* ptr;
ptr = animal->second ->animalID //pointer from a previously defined instance
 myAnimalID =*ptr
```

However, when I print, it only prints the first value of the wchar.

What am I doing wrong to where I can't print the entire value? I tried specifying the size of the myAnimalID wchar_t value, but I got an access violation error.

I know similar questions have been asked, but I didn't want to ask questions on old threads.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: 1. are you using `wcout`? 2. note that ptr is valid as long as the iterator is valid. means ptr point to nowhere after the iterator was changed or was released.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please. Your question is off-topic in it's current form. Thank you for obeying all the quality policies and constraints on Stack Overflow.

Comment: _"the first value of the wchar"_ That _is_ the entire value. A `wchar_t` is one [wide] character.

Comment: BTW what's this got to do with memory leaks?

Comment: In another question similar to this one, someone said that a wchar_t value only points to one character. So it causes a memory leak bc there isn't enough space for the rest of the characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `*ptr` you dereference the pointer and access the first element of it. If `animalID` is a `wchart_t*` then just assigning that to `myAnimalID` should be enough.

```
std::wstring myAnimalID = animal->second ->animalID;
```

Comment: That worked! And I understand my error. Thanks a lot.